# Get Last Element of a/an List/Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split

Sometimes I need to get the last element in an Array if I split something. Although I didn't found any way to do it better than this way:

```
_Path.Split('\\')[_Path.Split('\\').Length - 1]
```

Is there maybe an easier way to do this than this one? In this case it's pretty nice to understand, but if it gets longer, it isn't anymore.

Comment: Use Linq. `_Path.Split('\\').Last()`. Duplicate question. please search before asking new question

Comment: using System.Linq; var last = _Path.Split('\\').Last();

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`Last`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) or [`LastOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301849.aspx) extension methods:

```
_Path.Split('\\').Last()
```

- `Last` will throw an exception if there are no elements
- `LastOrDefault` will return the default value - `default(T)` - which is `null` for reference types

You need to add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: It always scared me a bit because of the IEnumerable stuff, but if it works how you wrote it then it's ok ^^

Comment: @DanielFrühauf it's perfectly fine. Why did it scare you? LINQ to objects is a *very* powerful toolset, and it's worth to master it.

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ's method `Last()`:

```
_Path.Split('\\').Last();
```

Don't forget `using System.Linq;` is required.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there maybe an easier way to do this than this one?

Yes, using [`Enumerable.Last`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358775(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var last = _Path.Split('\\').Last();
```

If you're not sure `Path.Split` will yield any items, use [`Enumerable.LastOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault(v=vs.95).aspx) and check against null.

```
var last = _Path.Split('\\').LastOrDefault();
if (last != null)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: `LastOrDefault()` too in case of empty array.

Comment: @M.kazem Yes, I was just editing.